# How to fix the cwebp command line error using the default exe?

Tags: shell, image-processing

I Downloaded the package from libwebp-1.3.2-windows-x64.zip.

cwebp -q 80 image.png -o image.webp
cwebp : The term 'cwebp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Is it possible to run the default exe and convert.

I want to run it on cmd.

Comment: You'll need to unzip the downloaded file and find the full path to `cwebp.exe`. Then use the full path in CMD.